# Moving triggers and sequences from one schema to another

Tags: sql, database, oracle, oracle11g

My problem consists of a need to move/copy triggers from one schema to another one. One of the problems is that I cannot create views crossing from schema1 to schema2, to solve this I want to move all to one big schema.

But doesn't appear that triggers and sequences will follow. Maybe I need to make a file ready that creates all triggers and sequences, and ensures that the sequences will be updated with the last number from the old schema..

Comment: I'd recommend to _always_ have a script file ready! (If you need to start a new server in a hurry, in case of emergency.)

Comment: Or you can use a tool like SQL Developer which have functionality to copy en mass objects

Comment: @jarlh what should that script file contain exactly? Perhaps you have a template example ?

Comment: All `create`, `grant` etc needed to re-create your dbms.

Comment: *" I cannot create views crossing from schema1 to schema2"* Why not? It is simple for one schema to grant privileges on its objects to another schema.

Comment: @apc I get Error during Execute
 S1000(1749)[Oracle][ODBC][Ora]ORA-01749:  you cannot grant/revoke priveleges to/from yourself.

Comment: You need somebody to connect to the schema which **owns the tables** and grant privileges to the user you connect as. If you don't have the authority to do that you will need to ask a person who does. .

Answer (score 2):

"One of the problems is that I cannot create views crossing from schema1 to schema2"

A possible solution is to leave everything where it is and grant the necessary permissions to create the view you need.

```
grant select on schema1.table to schema2;

create schema2.view as select * from schema1.table;
```

Comment: I sincerely hope this is the solution. So much better than merging two schemas into one.

Comment: I get Error during Execute
 S1000(1749)[Oracle][ODBC][Ora]ORA-01749:  you cannot grant/revoke priveleges to/from yourself.

Comment: You need to connect to schema1 to grant permission to schema2.

Answer (score 0):

Mayby try to generate DDL and put it in file via:

```
declare
cl clob;

begin
--(optional) for rec in (select * from all_views) loop

SELECT DBMS_METADATA.get_ddl ('VIEW', VIEW_NAME, VIEW_OWNER)
into   cl
from   dual;
dbms_output.put_line( cl);
end;
```

Comment: Umm, the problem is the OP cannot create the views in the first place, so there is no DDL to extract. It's everything else they want to shift.